# How To Use Axway Gateway With Sprig Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I've no idea about how to use the api gateway for AXWAY with Spring gateway ?
any one can advice me or give a me a lead ?

Comment: please provide samples on what you already tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Sombriks I don't have code i just want to add api management (AXWAY) To my manage my apis and i'am looking for someone to give a lead